# System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", xxx) not working in API rest?

Tags: java, rest

I have the following code and it works fine if I run it by console:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        String jSonData = "xxx";

        String nombreCertificadoTicket = "CERTIFICADO.p12";
        String passCertificadoTicket = "PASSWORD";
        String pathCertificado = "/opt/tomcat/properties/"+nombreCertificadoTicket;
        String url_crearTicket = "URL SERVICE";
        
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", pathCertificado);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", passCertificadoTicket);
        
        URL urlCrearTicket = new URL(url_crearTicket);                                                  
        
        HttpURLConnection conexionCrearTicket = (HttpURLConnection) urlCrearTicket.openConnection();
        conexionCrearTicket.setDoOutput(true);
        conexionCrearTicket.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conexionCrearTicket.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");

        OutputStream os = conexionCrearTicket.getOutputStream();
        os.write(jSonData.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        
        System.out.println("CODE :"+conexionCrearTicket.getResponseCode());
```

I execute this class by console and it executes and returns the code ok,
but I put exactly the same code in a rest service and it returns a 401 unauthorized error, therefore I assume that it is not placing the security certificate correctly.

```
@Path("PruebaCertificado")
public class PruebaCertificado {

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public RespuestaWs recibe(InputStream entrada) {
    
    RespuestaWs respuesta = new RespuestaWs();
    
    try {
        
        String jSonData = "";
        
        String jSonData = "xxx";

        String nombreCertificadoTicket = "CERTIFICADO.p12";
        String passCertificadoTicket = "PASSWORD";
        String pathCertificado = "/opt/tomcat/properties/"+nombreCertificadoTicket;
        String url_crearTicket = "URL SERVICE";
        
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", pathCertificado);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", passCertificadoTicket);
        
        URL urlCrearTicket = new URL(url_crearTicket);                                                  
        
        HttpURLConnection conexionCrearTicket = (HttpURLConnection) urlCrearTicket.openConnection();
        conexionCrearTicket.setDoOutput(true);
        conexionCrearTicket.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conexionCrearTicket.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");

        OutputStream os = conexionCrearTicket.getOutputStream();
        os.write(jSonData.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        
        System.out.println("CODE :"+conexionCrearTicket.getResponseCode());
```

Do I need to put some configuration in the tomcat or something like that?

The environment has Apache Tomcat 8 y Java 1.8

Comment: Try to put it in a class with the @Configuration annotation. But I think it's better to use HttpUrlConnection with a SSLContext and set there your keystores instead set the property.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with another code that I found, I leave it in case it works for someone. Notice I use HttpsURLConnection

```
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(pathCertificado);
        keyStore.load(keyInput, passCertificadoTicket.toCharArray());
        keyInput.close();
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, passCertificadoTicket.toCharArray());
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
        
        HttpsURLConnection conexionCrearTicket = (HttpsURLConnection) urlCrearTicket.openConnection();
        conexionCrearTicket.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        conexionCrearTicket.setDoOutput(true);
        conexionCrearTicket.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conexionCrearTicket.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
```